# What is the different between android:visibility and PropertySet android:visibility in Constraint

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I just started working with `MotionLayout`. After testing, I see that I can use both `android:visibility="gone"` or `PropertySet android:visibility="gone"` to hide a view.

```
<Constraint android:id="@+id/text_video_title"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >
    <PropertySet android:visibility="gone" />
</Constraint>
```

I check the [MotionLayout document](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout) but it doesn't mention. Is there any different between theme? May be it have some benefit of using `PropertySet android:visibility`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.
By default Constraints present in the layout file are used as the default in a  ConstraintSet.

The layout file for a ConstraintLayout or MotionLayout can contain 3 types of attributes.

1. Constraints that affect layout
2. View Transforms that apply post layout such as scaleX, rotate
3. Subclass specific attributes such as text

**ConstraintSets**

If you have more than the android:id attribute in the `<Constraint>` tag.
it erases all underlying constraints (type 1 and 2). Which means you will need to define all constraints needed to layout that view (things like layout_constraintTop_toTopOf=.. )

If you only have id and you have sub sections such as `<PropertySet> <Transform> <layout>`
It will erase only those sections you define.

2.1 adds  `<ConstraintOverride>` which will override only the tags you put but you cannot override layout_constraintXXX tags.